# How to configure nginx under 800 requests per second?

Tags: php, nginx, nuxt.js

Site front on NUXT and api on php.
NUXT is launched through pm2 in cluster mode in the number of 4 pieces.
api rotates on php-fpm and is proxy through nginx
now at some point during server-side rendering some requests are sagging and nginx is tearing up the connection, as a result some requests to the site are down.
how to configure nginx for this load? mysql ok,
htop shows the system load by 30-50%, there is still potential, and how to use it is incomprehensible

Comment: DNS, then app server load balancing, caching etc.. maybe 1 server is not enough..

Comment: What makes you think that nginx is the bottleneck?